# Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог добавлять блоки(своего рода карточки) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, create-react-app

Делаю приложение для создания распорядка дня на react-native. У меня есть готовые блоки по типу пробежка, чтение, сон и т.д. Я хочу чтобы пользователь нажимая на плюс, выбирал нужный и мог добавлять себе эти блоки, чтобы потом когда он заходил в приложение, там отображалось всё то что он поставил себе.

Comment: Ну отловите нажатие на нужную вам область экрана и вставьте блок в нужное вам место =)

Comment: Учите что такое массивы в js, их методы и как это все дело в jsx отрендерить